# Installation an application in Drive

Tags: google-drive-api

I search to install an GAE application in Drive (sample DrEdit with new API TR). All is OK, but I can not properly configure the "Google Drive SDK" (Part: Drive Integration) and the field "Install URL".

See screenshot (here: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6UEJFMrvusLY01XcHlXd0Fib2M/edit?ups=drive_web)

example of error:
Error :redirect_uri_mismatch
The redirect URI in the request: https://pcop-gd01.appspot.com did not match a registered redirect URI

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Install URL should be added to "Redirect URIs" in API Access section to resolve this error. There can be multiple Redirect URIs delimited by new line character.